# first and last value is not displaying in chart.js used with django

Tags: python, django, chart.js, chart.js2

i want to display the employee and salary in a graph, i used chart.js and django. but i cannot display the salary of first and last employee..any suggestion is appreciated.

```
#views
    if request.method=="GET":
        return render(request, 'upload_pandas.html')
    else:
        file=request.FILES['myfile']
        file_read=pd.read_excel(file)
        column_selection=file_read['Salary']
        salary=[]
        salary=list(column_selection)
        print(salary)
        name=[]
        name=list(file_read['First Name'])
        print(name)
        lis=[salary,name]
        data={
            'salary_data': salary,
            'label_data': name,

        }
        return render(request,'map.html',{'data':data})



#url.py

urlpatterns=[

    path('upload/',views.view_panda),

]
```

the problem is here, when i print in console it prints all the value but it was not loading in the graph.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z27rg.png)

```
#map.html

<html>
<head>

    <title>Chart.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    <div>
        <canvas id="genderchart" width="1000"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>

            var label={% autoescape off %}
                        "{{ data.salary_data }}"
                      {% endautoescape %};
            var label1={% autoescape off %}
                            "{{ data.label_data }}"
                       {% endautoescape %};
            var lab=label1.split(',')
            console.log(lab)
            console.log(label)
            console.log(label1)

            new Chart(document.getElementById("genderchart"),{
                type:'bar',
                data:{
                    labels:label1.split(','),
                    datasets:[
                        {
                            label:"employee",
                            backgroundColor:"rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            data: label.split(','),

                        },

                    ]
                },
                options:{
                    legend:{
                        labels:{
                            fontSize:18
                        }
                    },
                    title:{
                        display : true,
                        text : "Salary Wise",
                        fontSize : 22.0
                    },
                    scales:{
                        yAxes:[{
                            offset: true,

                            ticks:{
                                suggestedMin: true,
                                fontSize:15.0,
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display:true,
                                labelString:'Salary',
                                fontSize:20.0,
                            }
                        }],

                        xAxes:[{
                            desplay: true,
                            offset: true,
                            ticks:{
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                fontSize:15.0,

                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display:true,
                                labelString:'Employee',
                                fontSize:20.0,
                            }
                        }]
                     },
                    responsive: false,
                }
            });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i got it right ..the mistake was silly as i got the value with  " " that is

```
let data={% autoescape off %}
                   "{{ data }}"
                {% endautoescape %};
```

instead of

```
let data={% autoescape off %}
                  {{ data }}
         {% endautoescape %};
```

so , no need of split()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    <div>
        <canvas id="genderchart" width="1000"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
let data={% autoescape off %}
                        {{ data }}
                      {% endautoescape %};
console.log(data)


            new Chart(document.getElementById("genderchart"),{
                type:'bar',
                data:{
                    labels:data.label_data,
                    datasets:[
                        {
                            label:"employee",
                            backgroundColor:"rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            pointBackgroundColor:"rgba(62,149,205,1)",
                            data: data.salary_data,

                        },

                    ]
                },
                options:{
                    legend:{
                        labels:{
                            fontSize:18
                        }
                    },
                    title:{
                        display : true,
                        text : "Salary Wise",
                        fontSize : 22.0
                    },
                    scales:{
                        yAxes:[{
                            offset: true,

                            ticks:{
                                suggestedMin: 0,
                                fontSize:15.0,
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display:true,
                                labelString:'Salary',
                                fontSize:20.0,
                            }
                        }],

                        xAxes:[{
                            display: true,
                            offset: true,
                            ticks:{
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                fontSize:15.0,

                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display:true,
                                labelString:'Employee',
                                fontSize:20.0,
                            }
                        }]
                     },
                    responsive: false,
                }
            });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't reproduce your error. [Here](https://jsbin.com/zusaxununo/2/edit?html,js,output) is what I was doing with generated data (and it gets displayed fine).

```
const count = 26
for (let x = 0; x < count; x++) {
  sData.salary.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)*1000)
  sData.label.push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5))
}
```

Can you make an online editor version so we can check it easier?
I would guess the problem are the label strings or the options, but it's hard to guess...

Btw you have some spelling errors, e.g. "desplay", scriptsrc, and suggestedMin is no boolean, it's an int.